# Visual Studio 2008 compilation works; Same project compiled in 2010 doesn't

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-6, 64-bit

Have a project that was created in Visual Studio 2008 and deployed to a 64-bit Windows 2003 server.  This application references a 32-bit Interop.ActiveDs.dll.  The applications were originally compiled for 'Any CPU', however, explicitly compiling as 'x86' doesn't solve the problem.  The project targets the 3.5 framework.

The server is running IIS 6.0 in 64-bit mode.  When we deploy the version compiled in Visual Studio 2008, the app runs perfectly fine; all pages show up.  In retrospect, this is actually surprising.

We migrated the application to Visual Studio 2010 (we did not change the targeted framework) and redeployed.  Now we get a BadImageFormatException loading Interop.ActiveDs.dll.  Which actually makes more sense than the 2008 version running.

To solve the problem, we set Enable32bitAppOnWin64 to true and ran aspnet_regiis.exe -i from the 32-bit folder of the 2.0 framework (as per various instructions on the web).  In IIS, web service extensions, there were two versions of ASP.NET 2.0, one for 32-bit and one for 64-bit.  We prohibited the 64-bit version, restarted IIS, and launched the website.

What we expected:  The app to run as 32-bit, load the interop, and display
What we got:  "Service Unavailable"

All other web pages that were previously working displayed the same message, as did the Visual Studio 2008 version.

The support page [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/894435) describes the problem exactly, but tells us to do exactly what we did to resolve the problem (enable 32-bit mode).

We've rolled back to 64-bit mode in IIS and deployed the Visual Studio 2008 version for now, but we really need to figure out how to make this app run and load the interop (there are also 32-bit Oracle DLLs that are referenced)

Two questions:

1. Why does the Visual Studio 2008 version work at all??
2. How do we get the Visual Studio 2010 version to work?  And what is 2010 doing differently that causes the issue?

Thanks in advance!
James

Comment: Not compiling your application is an option you can consider? I'm not sure if it is a viable solution in your situation.

Comment: Oh, we compile it in VS 2008... and it works fine : \

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen if you have one DLL compiled for 64-bit and another in 32-bit.  Check through all of your references and look for those that do not have 64-bit versions.  If you can't find 64-bit versions of your incompatible DLLs, you will need to compile in 32-bit mode.

Comment: Yeah, we went through the configuration manager with a fine-toothed comb... all the dlls we build are in line with their respective configurations.  It's the interop that's tripping us; we don't build that.  Thanks though, any other ideas?

Comment: Sorry, no.  That's all I got.

Comment: Giving you credit for this... we used a different interop, and this one worked for us.  All I can think is that one of the interops was 64-bit, and the other 32... though it doesn't fit the facts; unless the migration modified the reference somehow, they should have been referencing the same DLL.  And the behavior of the DLLs just doesn't quite add up.  Considering this one "solved, with no understanding of the resolution".